# Leaks Instrument with Xcode stops iOS app in simulator

Tags: xcode, instruments

When I try to start the Leaks instrument (Xcode 9.3) it launches the iOS app OK within simulator, but then the app terminates after launching. Some other instruments do the same, but others (such as Core Data) seem to work OK. The only thing I can see from the simulator log is a reference to error 4. There seems to be a lack of any clues as to what is happening (unless I'm missing it), but I can't see what I can do to get Leaks operating properly.

If I run the App normally within simulator, or even on an actual device, it operates correctly.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd recommend filing a bug report with Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried changing the profile build from Release to Debug?

To do so, go into "Edit Schemes" -> Select "Profile" from left menu -> Change "Build Configuration" to Debug.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have tried as you suggest, but the app still halts just after startup even with the profile set to Debug.

Comment: when instrument ask you to select template, choose blank then in next window press '+' button (Right corner) and add desired items.